# Same animation is taking longer in different directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image slider, it's going to the next/previous image fine.
The problem is that when you click the previous image button, the animation takes longer than when you click in the next image button, and the animation is the same for both!
Can you tell me why is this happening?
JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/v6d16jza/
HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
            <div id="setas-navegacao" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;">
                <i class="sprite-slider_ant" style="z-index:1;position:absolute;left:1.7%;top:50%;color:#ffa500;font-size:15pt;"><</i>
                <i class="sprite-slider_prox" style="z-index:1;position:absolute;right:68.5%;top:50%;color:#ffa500;font-size:15pt;">></i>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide_ativo" style="background-image:url('http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images-540x303.jpg');">

            </div>

            <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg');">

            </div>

            <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/42/6914793-tropical-beach-images.jpg');">

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    overflow: hidden; 
    width:100%;
}
div#slider{
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 300%;
    height:300px;
}

.slide{
    position:relative;
    width:33.3%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.9s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 0.9s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left 0.9s ease-out;
    transition: margin-left 0.9s ease-out;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".sprite-slider_prox").on("click", function(){
    if($(".slide_ativo").next().is(".slide")){
        $(".slide_ativo").css("margin-left", "-100%").removeClass("slide_ativo").next().addClass("slide_ativo");
    }
});

$(".sprite-slider_ant").on("click", function(){
    if($(".slide_ativo").prev().is(".slide")){
        $(".slide_ativo").removeClass("slide_ativo").prev().css("margin-left", "0%").addClass("slide_ativo");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding more margin than it's actually needed to shift the image to the left.

You can see what's happening with the Chrome inspector, hovering the images while they change (raising the animation time to some higher value will help you). You will notice that the delay before the slider starts moving back is spent removing the extra margin.

I recorded a [video](https://vimeo.com/140470248) of the debugging.

If you change:

```
.css("margin-left", "-100%")
```

to:

```
.css("margin-left", "-33.333%")
```

the animation will work correctly (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acasaccia/v6d16jza/1/))

Also, note that I had to remove the padding and margin from `html` and `body` elements to achieve the correct shifting.

Comment: That's beaultiful! Although I don't get why it was slower going back. Thank you very much!